# 100% width is bigger than parent's div

Tags: html, css, width

I'm working on vBulletin theme, but on thread list, every thread has 100% for its width but threads are also bigger than their parents, but when i remove border of threads, they will fit parent's div:). so think this problem is on borders.

You can see that better on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wKmGu/) (thread is white shape with black border)

```html
<body>
   <div class="after-body">
        <div class="body-wrapper">
             <div class="threadlist">
                    <ol class="threads">
                        <li class="threadbit"><div class="thread"></div></li>
                        <li class="threadbit"><div class="thread"></div></li>
                    </ol>
             </div>
        </div>
   </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 88, accepted):

The problem here is that the `width` is a size of the inner area with text, and the padding with border are "wrapped" around it. That specification makes no sense, but most modern browsers follow it.

Your savior is called `box-sizing: border-box;`.

```
.threadbit .thread {

    /* ... some stuff ... */

    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box; /* Safari/Chrome, other WebKit */
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;    /* Firefox, other Gecko */
    box-sizing: border-box;         /* Opera/IE 8+ */
}
```

Look here: **[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MightyPork/wKmGu/1/)**

More info on this property [here](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_box-sizing.asp) and [here](http://css-tricks.com/box-sizing/).

Comment: Just the answer I needed. My saviour !

Comment: https://caniuse.com/css3-boxsizing

Answer (score 5):

Yep you are right, the borders are pushing out the "width" of the element. The is the default [box-sizing](http://css-tricks.com/box-sizing/) of modern browsers. This can be modified in most with a declaration like:

```
.threadbit .thread { 
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box; /* Safari/Chrome, other WebKit */
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;    /* Firefox, other Gecko */
    box-sizing: border-box;         /* Opera/IE 8+ */
}
```

Note that it isn't supported below IE8 so depending what you are making and the support you want, you may need to find an alternative solution or design.

**EDIT**

It has been a while since my original answer and browser support has changed slightly. Firefox 29, Chrome 10, Safari 5.1 and Internet Explorer 8 onwards all support `box-sizing` unprefixed however there are a few known issues from particular versions.

The full/up-to-date list is available on [caniuse.com](http://caniuse.com/css3-boxsizing) however here is a few ones I found important from the site:

- IE8: ignores `box-sizing: border-box` if min/max-width/height is used
- IE8: the `min-width` property applies to `content-box` even if `box-sizing` is set to `border-box`
- IE9: the width of the scrollbar is subtracted from the width of the element when set to `position: absolute` and either `overflow: auto` or `overflow-y: scroll`

As the market share for IE8 and IE9 decrease, these issues and the other listed on caniuse will be less of an issue in the future.

Comment: Ctrl+C master, but he's not styling a textarea :P @ via http://css-tricks.com/box-sizing/

Comment: Clearly! Not a huge fan of posting just a link to a fiddle then editing my answer a bunch of times. ;) Got to be some element of practice and learning for the person asking the question too.

Comment: Oh yes, but it surely wouldn't hurt to replace `textarea` with `.threadbit .thread` in the copied snippet?

Comment: That article seems outdated re: browser support.  Chrome and FF have supported unprefixed `box-sizing` for a while.

Comment: Cheers for the information @cHao, updated the post to reflect updated browser support. Apparently though [FF still isn't unprefixed](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=CSS%2Fbox-sizing#Notes).

Answer (score 5):

Always remember when you encounter problems related to width check dimensions of element through box model from firefox developer tool or from chrome's metrix box.
Its alway a good idea to include

```
  *, *:before, *:after {
      -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
      -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
      box-sizing: border-box;
     }
```

Also make sure to check display property. If a element is made display inline it won't take width, margin & padding values and if it is displayed as inline-block it take width, margin & padding.

Here is a link for box-sizing property http://www.paulirish.com/2012/box-sizing-border-box-ftw/