# Why 100% width crosses the parrent div?

Tags: css

UPDATE: [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18031354/100-width-is-bigger-than-parents-div) is not working. Have a look at [this pen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/LExVep)

I set width of the div 700px but If I add a child div 100% width then the child div cross parent div's boundary and the actual size of child div is 730px . Why?[codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/myRJzw)

```
<div class="container">
  <h1>Drive Nuts</h1>
 <div class="info">
  <div class="left">Call No.</div>
  <div class="right">Datas</div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Css:

```
    body {
       background: #34495e; 
       padding: 50px 0px;
    }

   .container {
       background: #ecf0f1; 
       min-height:480px; 
       width:700px; margin: 0px auto;
    }
    .container h1 {
       text-align: center;
       background: #27ae60; 
       color: #ecf0f1; 
       line-height: 90px; margin: 0px;
     }

     .left  {
       background: #16a085;
       padding:15px; 
       font-weight: bold; 
       font-size: 20px; 
       color: #fff; 
       width:150px; float:left;
     }

     .right  { 
       padding:15px;
       font-weight: bold; 
       font-size: 20px; 
       color: #fff; 
       width:; 
       float:left; 
       background: #2c3e50;
       width:100%;
    }
```

Comment: You must understand the box model. Then use the rule box-sizing to resolve it.  http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/box-sizing-secret-simple-css-layouts

Comment: even http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18031354/100-width-is-bigger-than-parents-div is not working. http://codepen.io/anon/pen/LExVep

Comment: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/vEgOwZ WORKS

Comment: Yes its working... just add the rule box-sizing: border-box; to right class  http://codepen.io/anon/pen/MYJwRd . Just i mentioned above on the first comment.

Comment: I see.. border-box belongs to child div. not to the parent.

Answer (score 2):

You have to remove the `padding`(`30px`) from the `width`. You could use `calc()` to do it.

```
.right {
    padding: 15px;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 20px;
    color: #FFF;
    float: left;
    background: none repeat scroll 0% 0% #2C3E50;
    width: calc(100% - 30px);
}
```

[image]

Comment: I know I can fit it by -30 but my question is 'why'

Comment: @SahriarSaikat - Well, you are adding `padding`, so ofcourse the width is going to be more than the parent's width.